# mod_wsgi windows 7 64 bit installation issue

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I am getting this error, in windows 7 home prime edition 64 bit environment.
I had tried many different ways as described in apache documentation. 
In httpd.conf  I have the following
Environment  Python 3.4 , apache 2.4.25 
mod_wsgi py25 vc10 64 bit.  Further i had tried to run Python code 
thru CGI , it is working fine.

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonEggs /apache2423/Apache24/htdocs
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi /apache2423/Apache24/htdocs/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /Python34
<Directory /apache2423/Apache24/htdocs/>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

The code was:

```
#!/Python34/python
import os
import subprocess

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/Apache245/Apache24/htdocs'

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'<html> ... Hello World of Django ...</html>'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'), ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

Comment: And what is the error? Where do you see that error? What messages are in the Apache error log?

Comment: I  had tried to run this code.     #!/Python34/python
import os
import subprocess
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/Apache245/Apache24/htdocs'

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'

    output = b'<html> ... Hello World of Django ...</html>'


    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]

    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question as to what the problem was, where you saw any error etc. Details about the error are required. It is impossible to guess without details.

Comment: I try to start apache server (httpd.exe) thru command prompt. No error message in log

Comment: You said you got an error though. What was the error? Did you get an error in the web browser when making a request to the application? Was it an error from ``httpd`` when you ran it? If from the browser when making a request, what URL did you use?

Comment: I  try to start apache server thru command prompt.  I had  installed apache 2.4.25 and navigated thru bin and try to ran httpd.exe

Comment: C:\Apache245\Apache24\bin>httpd
httpd: Syntax error on line 544 of C:/Apache245/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: T
 module could not be found.

Comment: Does the directory ``/apache2423/Apache24//modules`` even contain a file ``mod_wsgi.so``? Where did you get mod_wsgi in the first place and how did you install it?

Comment: it shows a line number it is wrong. line 544 in httpd.conf did is a commented line. mod_wsgi.so exists in  modules/ folder. folder structure as below

Comment: C:\Apache245\Apache24\modules

Comment: i want to run django framework web project code with apache http server

Comment: presently i am trying to run hello world code for testing.

Comment: Why do you have some paths as ``/apache2423/Apache24`` and others as ``/Apache245/Apache24``? Do you definitely only have one Apache installation?

Comment: i got  mod_wsgi py3.4 vc10 built binaries here

Comment: http://grapevine.dyndns-ip.com/download/folder.asp?eid=33&folder=%2Fdownload%2Fapache%2Fmod_wsgi-windows-4.4.6%2Fmod_wsgi-windows-4.4.6%2Fapache24-win64-vc10%2Fmodules%2F

Comment: I have apache installation. I tired both version  apache 2.4.23 and apache 2.4.25 with the same  mod_wsgi.so.  As per documentation binaries build with  VC10 will work on windows 7 64 bit environment

Comment: I am not running apace as a service. Running as  httpd.exe in command line

Comment: I  read all previous thread related this error before I post my message.

Comment: I had unstalled 2.4.23 and try to run thru only one apache installation apache 2.4.25 and getting the same error

Comment: C:\Apache245\Apache24\bin>httpd
httpd: Syntax error on line 544 of C:/Apache245/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi.so into s
 module could not be found.

Comment: Directory of C:\Apache245\Apache24\modules

12/31/2016  04:11 PM           104,960 mod_wsgi.so
               1 File(s)        104,960 bytes

Comment: Graham thanks a lot. It works now.

Comment: BTW. If your system is setup with a compiler so that ``pip install xxx`` works for a Python package which contains C extensions. You can run ``pip install mod_wsgi``. Then run ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` and it will output the values to use for loading mod_wsgi into Apache. That means can compile latest mod_wsgi version any time you want rather than rely on grabbing a binary from someone you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that the `mod_wsgi.so` file is correctly in the Apache modules directory, change your Apache configuration to:

```
LoadFile /Python34/DLLs/python3.dll
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /Python34

WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi /apache2423/Apache24/htdocs/wsgi.py

<Directory /apache2423/Apache24/htdocs/>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Confirm that:

```
/Python34/DLLs/python3.dll
```

does actually exist. It should be the location of the Python 3.4 DLL.

It is presumed that your Python 3.4 is installed under `/Python34`.

The point of the `LoadFile` line is to force loading of the Python DLL. The error you get can also mean it was the DLL referenced by `mod_wsgi.so` wasn't found in any of the standard locations.

The `WSGIPythonHome` is telling mod_wsgi where the Python installation is. Note that it isn't `WSGIPythonPath` as you had.

The URL you would use to access the application would be `http://localhost/wsgi`.